# Small Question about a heat conduction problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the solution $y(x,t)$ in $0<x<3$ and $t≥0$ for the following heat conduction problem:

$2y_t=y_{xx}$;     $y_x(0,t)=y_x(3,t)=0$;     $y(x,0)=g(x)$

Where $g(x)$ is a generic function.  Derive your solution using separation of variables.

I worked through the problem until I got confused in the end.  Where does the $\frac{2}{3}$ come from in the solutions?

$\displaystyle A_0=\frac{2}{3}\int_0^33g(x)dx$

$\displaystyle A_n=\frac{2}{3}\int_0^3 g(x)cos(\frac{n\pi x}{3})dx$

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it looks correct.  Thanks for helping me out, I'm still trying to learn the code!

Comment: Remember that Fourier series of $f(x)$ in $x\in(0,L)$ is defined as $$f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos \left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right) + b_n \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$$ where $$a_n(x) = \frac{2}{L}\int_0^L f(x) \cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)dx$$ and $$b_n = \frac{2}{L}\int_0^L f(x) \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)dx.$$

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Apologies if I'm wrong but shouldn't there be an extra factor of 2 under the sines/cosines?

Comment: @DepeHb Actually in the considered case we need cosine Fourier series on $(0,L)$, which means 1) $b_n=0$, the full Fourier series is sought on $(-L,L)$ for an even extension of $g(x)$. With this caveat, the formula for $a_n$ is correct.